# Рисование графов C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, графы, поиск-библиотек, graph

необходимо рисовать на winform графы имея лишь матрицы расстояний между пунктами.

В дальнейшем буду отображать на них решения задачи коммивояжера.

Какие средства использовать?

P.S. Размеры матриц постоянно разнятся, заполняются рандомом; вручную отрисовывать не вариант

Comment: Просто что первое попалось в гугле https://github.com/microsoft/automatic-graph-layout/blob/master/README.md